# using a class and @media css

Tags: html, css

I tried to use this code but my list shows a margin on the left of the page

```
 @media(max-width: 900px){
 ul{    
  width:100%;       
 }       
 ul li{ 
    width:100%; 
 }

 ul li a {  
    text-align:center;  
    width:100%;     
    height:30px;    
    line-height:30px;   
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    outline:rgba(255,255,255,0.9) solid 1px; 
 }
```

I don't know what instruction should I use or what to change so there is no left margin I have a header with this class

```
header {    
  margin-top:0px;   
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  height:140px;         
}
```

Comment: try to add ul{ margin-left:0px;} by default ul element has some margin on left . Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle maybe or at least post the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UL has padding on the left; not a margin.
Use `ul {padding-left:0;}`

Also UL and LI will be 100% width by default as they are both block-level elements. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Hi used to this**

```
@media(max-width: 900px){
   // you can write your css here 

   .class{
      // write your css property 
   }
}
```